# python find the elements in array if it doesn't overlap an input and within each others

Tags: arrays, algorithm, list, python-2.7, recursion

I have a list of list like this :

```
data [["m1",10,30,10**-10],["m2",22,40,10**-9],["m3",30,50,10**-8],["m4",45,65,10**-7]]
```

The input is :

```
    [10,20]
```

I want to get a list of elements that 1) do not overlap with input coordinates, and 2) do not overlap with each other

```
1)      ["m2",22,40,10**-9],["m3",30,50,10**-8],["m4",45,65,10**-7]
```

In case there is overlap I need to choose the element with lowest last column

so the final output will be

```
["m2",22,40,10**-9],["m4",45,65,10**-7]
```

The overlap function is done but I couldn't figure how to  get this output.

Comment: explain with output for your input, edit your question otherwise you'll invite more downvotes

Comment: @sasha hope it's clearer now

Comment: Is the last column of each element meant to evaluate to a small floating point number, as opposed to computing the bitwise XOR of two values (the usual meaning of `^` in Python)?  If so, the notation should be like `10**-10`, `10**-8`, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made a little algorithm for you that will assure you have what you want, supposing you know how to check for overlap.

- define arrray of final result
- for each item1 in the data
- check if item DOES NOT overlap with input

> if yes: - for each item2 in final result
>               - check if item1 overlap with item2
>
> > if no: - add item1 in final result
> >     if yes: - check if last value of item2 smaller than last value of item1
> >     if yes: - remove item1 from final list, - add item2 to final list